# Use Rails' select() to add (not overwrite) selected attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a convenience scope that `includes` related models to speed up rendering of tables, etc:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  ...

  scope :includes_for_post_row, -> { includes(:reasons).includes(:feedbacks => [:user]) }
```

It works fine. Now, however, I'd like to `select` an additional attribute. If I already knew what initial attributes I wanted, I could do this (in the console):

```
2.3.3 :005 > Post.select("`posts`.*, 42 AS column_forty_two").last.column_forty_two
  Post Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  `posts`.*, 42 AS column_forty_two FROM `posts` ORDER BY `posts`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
 => 42
```

This assumes that I know I want to select `posts.*`, then I just tack on my `column_forty_two` column and it all works.

I want to add `column_forty_two` to my results, without affecting the initial select. For example, this should work:

```
p = Post.select("`posts`.*, 8 as column_eight").includes_for_post_row_with_forty_two
p.last.column_forty_two # => 42
p.last.column_eight # => 8
p.last.some_activerecord_property # => value
```

As should this:

```
p = Post.all.includes_for_post_row_with_forty_two.last
p.last.column_forty_two # => 42
p.last.some_activerecord_property # => value
```

How can I `select` an *additional* column, without affecting or overwrite the existing columns selected by default by `.all` or my own earlier `select`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you go digging through the ActiveRecord source (an often necessary task with Rails), [you'll see what's going on](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.0.1/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb#L1096):

```
def build_select(arel)
  if select_values.any?
    arel.project(*arel_columns(select_values.uniq))
  else
    arel.project(@klass.arel_table[Arel.star])
  end
end
```

`select_values` is a list of everything you've handed to `select` and is an empty array by default:

```
> Model.where(...).select_values
 => [] 
> Model.where(...).select('a').select_values
 => ["a"] 
> Model.where(...).select('a').select('b').select_values
 => ["a", "b"]
```

and when ActiveRecord finally gets around to building the SELECT clause, it either uses what you've passed to `select` (the `if` branch in `build_select`) or it uses `table_name.*` (the `else` branch in `build_select`).

You should be able to use the same logic that `build_select` uses to ensure that `select_values` has something before you start adding more so that you sort of execute both the `if` and `else` branches of `build_select` by pre-filling `select_values` with the default `table_name.*`. You could patch your own version of `select` into the `ActiveRecord::QueryMethods` module:

```
module ActiveRecord
  module QueryMethods
    def select_append(*fields)
      if(!select_values.any?)
        fields.unshift(arel_table[Arel.star])
      end
      select(*fields)
    end
  end
end
```

and then say things like:

```
> Post.select_append('6 as column_six').to_sql
 => "select `posts`.*, 6 as column_six from ..."
```

while leaving the "normal" `select` behavior alone:

```
> Post.select('11 as column_eleven').to_sql
 => "select 11 as column_eleven from ..."
```

You don't have to monkey patch of course but it seems reasonable for this sort of thing.

Comment: I have used this, but when chaining scopes it didn't work on 4.1. I had to add `delegate :select_append, to: :all` to `ActiveRecord::Querying` as well.

Also, if anyone else wants to combine this with  the columns_on_demand gem, you will have to replace `arel_table[Arel.tar]` by `default_select(true)`

Comment: I'm not being able to patch `ActiveRecord::QueryMethods`. I placed the code in `app/lib/active_record/query_methods.rb` but the new `select_append` method is not available in my models

Comment: @AndresEspinosa Normally you'd put that in `lib/active_record/query_methods.rb` and then add an initializer to require it.